# Windows Phone 8 - GPS location speed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to get gps speed every time when location updates.
Right now I'm doing like this:

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 0;
geolocator.MovementThreshold = 100;

geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;

void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        SpeedBlock.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Speed.ToString();

        LatitudeTextBlock.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
        LongitudeTextBlock.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
    });
}
```

This code works well for getting Latitude and Longitude, but speed always comes wrong. 
On emulator speed always shows 5.6 m/s. On device, its always 0.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check out the this article http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/understanding-the-windows-phone-location-service-how-to-get-current-gps-coordinates ?

It has as note:

> Altitude, Course and Speed are only available when you specify that
>   you want High accuracy location information by using
>   GeoPositionAccuracy.High instead of GeoPositionAccuracy.Default and
>   this data is retrieved from the GPS receiver. So if you try this
>   sample with the Default accuracy, you will get NaN for altitude, speed
>   and course. Unfortunately, although it is more accurate, High accuracy
>   uses more power and can take longer to determine your position. If you
>   are testing your app indoors it may still show NaN as a result for
>   Altitude, Course and Speed, because of weak GPS signal.

Also do take a look at this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521530/A-Windows-Phone-Run-Tracking-App-in-Lines-of
It show how to do your own pace calculation - but it depends on the scenario of the app.

Comment: The Nokia example that you provided is a dead link now.

Comment: Change the url to the original article